# different Response objects from SOAP Webservice?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

In JAX-WS usually the response object will be a string or an XML format.

Can we have 2 kinds of response objects.

I mean, based on flag, XML or JSON as response output?

Is there any Objectwrapper kind of solution?

Am new to JAX-WS ,So am totally clueless. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP#Message_format), you don't need XML to represent the SOAP message. But it looks like you will need SOAP bindings that support JSON. Reading the description in that article makes it sound like you can't just set a flag and have the response format change based on that.

If you want something where you set a flag to generate a different response format, consider a [REST architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) instead. In REST, you would send a different `Accept` header to specify the format of the response you want. There wouldn't need to be a flag in your application specific data to handle the data format since that's more of metadata concern anyways.